# LinearLayout not showing an item that was added programatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to add a textview and a button to a linear layout programatically.

The button is showing up but the textview isn't.

Here is my code:

```
        LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        LinearLayout first = new LinearLayout(this);

        LayoutParams fparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5.0f);
        LayoutParams tvparams = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LayoutParams btparams = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        first.setLayoutParams(fparams);
        first.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tvparams.weight = 3.0f;
        tv.setLayoutParams(tvparams);

        Button bt = new Button(this);
        btparams.weight = 2.0f;
        bt.setLayoutParams(btparams);

        first.addView(bt);
        first.addView(tv);      
        main.addView(first);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting some text on the `TextView`. Use it's `setText()` method

Answer (score 0):

ok try this to set programmatically

```
        LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent);
 LayoutParams fparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5.0f);
        LayoutParams tvparams = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,3.0f);
        LayoutParams btparams = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,2.0f);
        LinearLayout first = new LinearLayout(this);
        first.setLayoutParams(fparams);
        first.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("asdsad");
        tv.setLayoutParams(tvparams);

        Button bt = new Button(this);
        bt.setLayoutParams(btparams);

        first.addView(bt);
        first.addView(tv);      
        myLayout.addView(first);
```

hope it ll help,working for me correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The other answer was more to the point though.